# Как в бета версии сделать отправку определенных данных разработчику?

Tags: java, android, playmarket

Разместил Бета версию приложения в PlayMarket.
На период тестирования в приложении будет кнопка "Отправка статистики разработчику". При нажатии будет формироваться определенный отчет с данными, который надо передать мне, разработчику.

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Мне кажется самый простой вариант- отчет в формате Json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, если у вас есть какой-то сервер, способный принять и обработать запрос, то достаточно будет отправить запрос c JSON пакетом на указанный адрес. Можно попробовать отправить непосредственно письмо - но с этим сложнее (я бы не рекомендовал с этим связываться). Можно пойти еще одним путем - добавить облачный сервис (например firebase) и писать логи в облачную базу. Это несколько громоздко, но работать будет как надо. Далее вы результат можете просмотреть прямо в браузере с любого устройства =) Но это только если не хотите запариваться написание сервера.

Comment: с сервером заморачиваться не хочу и не очень в этом разбираюсь, firebase пробовал, но что-то у меня не пошло и пока не разобрался. Я думал что у PlayMarket есть какие-то возможности для этой задачи. Но все равно спасибо. Подожду еще, может будут еще варианты.

Comment: firebase достаточно просто, только нужно немного разобраться. Регистрируете прилоэжение в облочном сервисе. Изменяете правило для базы: писать и читать могут все (не нужна регистрация и авторизация). И небольшим кол-вом кода делаете всего 1 запрос на запись.